# LabVIEW delete array subset with bool array

Tags: labview

I want to create an array mask which uses some logic bool to preserve array value like the python demo.

```
a=np.array([5,10,7,-8,6,-9,8])
b=np.array([1,-3,20,5,7,20,5])
mask= ((a<=10) & (0<=a)) & ((b<=10) & (0<=b))
Pa=a[mask]
Pb=b[mask]
```

the result is

```
Pa=[5 6 8]
Pb=[1 7 5]
```

And I have use LabVIEW create the mask bool array
how can I get the same result without for loop, because my problem array is so large that couldn't real time run.
thanks.
below images are LabVIEW code

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The comparison operators ( = and in range?) can work on arrays. The resulting boolean array will have the same size as the largest of original arrays.